# Limit number of sessions per login name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to limit the number of logins throw the application to the SQL Server. So at the same time only one application could be opened by the user I have used the stored procedure below after starting the application but it seems like after passing some minutes like 10 or 15, although the app is open the session will be killed and the user is able to open the application again.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE gnr.sessionsLimiter
    @err VARCHAR(max) OUT    
AS    
    SELECT @err = ''    
    
    IF EXISTS (    
        SELECT Count(1)    
        FROM sys.sysprocesses    
        WHERE program_name = 'Startup'   
        GROUP BY loginame
        HAVING count(1) > 1    
    )    
    BEGIN    
        SELECT @err = 'the application is open in another place'    
    END
```

Comment: Why did you need to limit sqlserver connection session?

Comment: our application is an office application and users open two application at the same time and we want to prevent them from this

Comment: There might many way can limit connection (for example from `AP`) I would not suggest you limit that in DB

Comment: what if I have to do it on db ?

Comment: Believe this has an answer on Stack Exchange. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/how-to-limit-the-number-of-sessions-for-a-specific-login?msclkid=3464517bb4f411ec85a829a00497fce4